# How can i get username througth queryset?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, djoser

I have some model:

```
class Comments(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user_comment', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

heading = models.CharField(max_length=100)
score = models.IntegerField(default = 1, validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(5)])
text = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Meta:
    ordering = ['-created_at',]

def __str__(self):
    return self.heading
```

And i when make .get request in shell:

```
Comments.objects.get(pk=1).user
```

I get:

```
<User: user9>
```

But when i make that request:

```
 Comments.objects.filter(pk=1).values('user')
```

I get:

```
<QuerySet [{'user': 9}]>
```

For some reason, in the queryset I get only id, but not username. Due to the peculiarities of my application, I need to use exactly .filter or .all (), so I must somehow get the username in the queryset. Please help me.

Comment: `Comments.objects.get(pk=1).user.username`, or `Comments.objects.get(pk=1).values('user__username')`

Comment: But you should not use `.values` or `.values_list`, only for a very limited number of applications these are useful, and this is often only for aggregates on something different than a relation.

Comment: But why you are getting usernames in the querysets, if you have to show it in the template, so you can simply do it through adding `.username` at the end of context variable, which you passed through the view.

Comment: Just i use rest framework, and I get my model views as json:
[{
                "id": 17,
                "user": 10,
                "heading": "dfsdsfsdf",
                "score": 2,
                "text": "asdasdasd",
                "created_at": "2022-05-29T19:00:58.825347Z"
           {
                "id": 17,
                "user": 10,
                "heading": "sdfsdfdsf",
                "score": 2,
                "text": "asdasd)",
                "created_at": "2022-05-29T19:00:58.825347Z"
            }]

Comment: And i need get username in that json list, but not user_id

Comment: UPD. I figured out the problem: 
In serializer i use:     
user = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='username', read_only=True)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get all usernames from the QuerySet:

```
usernames = Comments.objects.filter(pk=1).values_list('username', flat=True)
```

If you want to get the first username from the QuerySet:

```
comment_qs = Comments.objects.filter(pk=1).values_list('username', flat=True)
username = comment_qs.first() if comment_qs.exists() else 'Unknown'
```

or

```
try:
    comment = Comments.objects.get(pk=1)
except Comments.DoesNotExist:
    username = 'Unknown'
else:
    username = comment.username
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the index to get the object.

```
print(Comments.objects.filter(pk=1)[0].username)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the id because Django writes the relation as an ID of the object that is related to the other object. For instance, in the table Comment in your database, the column `user` keeps the ID of the row of the table `User`.

To actually get the username your can simply do
`Comments.objects.filter(pk=1).values('user__username')`